# locale: Reset lost settings

Tags: locale

Due to some strange reason, I've lost some of my `locale` settings. I've managed to restore most of them using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

So I'm stuck with one missing value:

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Any idea how to restore them all?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you've deleted some files, try reinstalling the locale package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall locales
```

You may want to do the same for language-support-(your langcode), language-pack-(your langcode)-base and other language packs (gnome, kde...) for your language.

Answer (score 8):

Happens to me occasionally too. Not sure what causes it but I just fire off:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

And that seems to fix it (for me)

Answer (score 4):

This is what I had to do to fix this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall language-support-en
```

Answer (score 2):

Any of given answers didn't help me, but I found this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12183173&postcount=6

and it made the trick.

Comment: Can you explain how its work?

Comment: My case was this: Ubuntu froze and I've had to shut the laptop down. When I logged in, some (but not all) window titles etc. were in Chinese. Following the post instructions helped (I'm using a non-english (Croatian) locale) since my settings were overriten with zh_CH (chinese)

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem from time to time and none of the above answers help me. What actually helps me is adding the following to /etc/default/locales

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```