# Locale settings are not right. How can I reset them?

Tags: locale

I've got a locale problem.
The collating sequence in `nautilus` and other programs has changed.
I get locale errors appearing in the terminal when I launch a GUI app..

```
    Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

The `locale` command produces error messages

```
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    LANG=en_AU
    LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
    LC_CTYPE="en_AU"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_AU"
    LC_TIME="en_AU"
    LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8
    LC_MONETARY="en_AU"
    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8
    LC_PAPER="en_AU"
    LC_NAME="en_AU"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_AU"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU"
    LC_ALL=
```

As suggested in [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17001/how-to-set-locale), I've run the following commands, but there was no change.

```
    sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

I also tried the suggestion in [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2855/locale-reset-lost-settings)... also no change.

```
    apt-get install --reinstall locales
```

I *think* it began when I temporarily installed and uninstalled the Urdu language Input Method Editor via `IBus` .. it certainly happened on the same day.

Maybe it is IBus related, but I've not had any problems with it before this.

- The OS is 10.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I rebooted 12.04, certain menus are in Chinese/Japanese!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130649/when-i-rebooted-12-04-certain-menus-are-in-chinese-japanese)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've managed to get things running "normally" again.

After trying lots of package re-installs etc, including fully removing IBus (all to no effect),  I started to think that it may be caused by a config setting which re-installing doesn't modify.

I had noticed that the output from `locale` was rather bereft, of UTF-8 assignments, so I checked this in a recently installed VM...  all entries of LC_* (except LC_ALL, which overrides **all** the others) were set with the `.UTF-8` suffix. 
so I manually set the LC_* values as shown below.

I probably could have just used `LC_ALL="en_AU.UTF-8"`, but in reading up about this, I've discovered how to customize the [system date and time format](http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/), and `LC_ALL` would override my custom setting.

I don't know if I've used the most appropriate method, but it works!

The modified file is: `/etc/default/locale`

- *This shows the contents before the mod:*

  ```
  LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"
  LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
  ```
- *This shows the contents **after** the mod:*

  ```
  LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"
  LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8
  LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8
  LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
  LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
  ```

---

The same file in the VM contained only this one line:

```
    LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
```

---

Comment: thanks for your post. For the record, I had to restart my system for the fix to work. (perhaps could have used emacs eval-buffer?)

Answer (score 25):

Redefining the locales and reconfiguring might be sufficient to fix the problem:

```
sudo locale-gen en_AU.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

When you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` you can select the locale you want by clicking on <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and moving with <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to mention that you select languages you want with spacebar.

Comment: @Daniel I don't understand: spacebar ?

Comment: When running `dpkg-reconfigure` you get list with checkboxes and to select language you have to use spacebar. There's no such information in console program so I thought it would help to write it under the answer. I didn't know how to select these languages.

Comment: @Daniel done :)

Comment: You're a lifesaver @DanielKmak

Answer (score 15):

I also met this problem ,as you see, your `LC_ALL` is empty. I did as follows and it helps:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/environment
```

and set the `LC_ALL` to something like `en_US.UTF-8`,mine is:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

then reboot,and run `locale` ,and it should be something like:

```
LANG=zh_CN.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: This solution works well on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS precise

Comment: Setting `LC_ALL` is discouraged. "Using LC_ALL is strongly discouraged as it overrides everything. Please use it only when testing and never set it in a startup file." https://wiki.debian.org/Locale

Answer (score 5):

If you are remotely connected to the machine over ssh (eg from a macosx device) you need to set these variables on the machine you are connecting from

add the following to ~/.bash_profile

```
#fix for locale issues when connecting to ubuntu servers
export LANG="en_US.utf8"
export LANGUAGE="en_US.utf8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.utf8"
```

Comment: Is this a known fault when connecting from OS X?

Comment: no idea if this is by design or a fault/bug

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add, that I needed to edit my home profile too:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

So in your case it would look like:

```
...
LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"
```

Log out + Log in. And all is as expected.

Comment: I needed `export` at the beginning of each line, and I put it in `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for several months, a lot of software tools warned about broken locale settings, and some even refused to run. I want to use English language, but Swedish monetary and number settings.

What finally worked for me was to edit `/etc/default/locale` where I removed everything in that file. 
I then started the Unity language setup `(Settings -> Language Support)`, set everything up (Ubuntu wanted to install some missing components) and pressed `"Apply System-wide"` when I was done.

My `/etc/default/locale` now looks like this.

```
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en"
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

The big difference between this and my original file is `LANGUAGE="en"`.

Comment: My life saver...

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since this was posted but recently I had problems with "locale" variables and no answer gave me any results. Maybe my own experience could help someone else.

My **LANG** variable was empty, and this was giving me problems.

```
$locale
```

Output:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=POSIX
LC_NUMERIC=POSIX
LC_TIME=POSIX
LC_COLLATE=POSIX
LC_MONETARY=POSIX
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=POSIX
LC_NAME=POSIX
LC_ADDRESS=POSIX
LC_TELEPHONE=POSIX
LC_MEASUREMENT=POSIX
LC_IDENTIFICATION=POSIX
LC_ALL=POSIX
```

I tried some of the commands like:

```
sudo locale-gen
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

With no success. I tried editing the **/etc/default/locale** and find out it was already O.K:

```
$cat /etc/default/locale
```

Output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_CO.UTF-8"
```

Also my **.pam_environment** file seemed to be right:

```
$cat .pam_environment
```

Output:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_CO.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=letter
```

I din't want to add extra stuff to profile or bash files, mainly because although it could solve the problem I wouldn't know the cause, and that annoyed me.

Finally I wondered if something was already overriding "locale" variables and I ran the next command:

```
$cat .bashrc | grep LANG
```

Output:

```
unset LANG
```

So I found two lines on my **.bashrc** file that where the cause (I'm not pasting the whole file):

```
unset LANG
export LC_ALL=POSIX
```

I don't know how or when those lines ended up on my bash file, but I'm completely sure I didn't write them, maybe my .bashrc was replaced when I was working with some web-development stuff, I really don't know, but since I know this was unintentional and there are people out there with no clue about what's causing "locale" misbehavior, maybe this could help them. Anyway commenting those lines and a reboot solved the problem for me.
[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440320/setting-lang-for-sublimetext-from-unity/661628#661628) I answered the same question focused on sublimeT3 complaints about the **LANG** variable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems an update fried locales somehow.
The fix I found was to log out, change the language selected before logging in, and logging in again.

It might also help to reinstall the locales in synaptic, though I cannot confirm that this is what fixed it for me, I think it was logging out or something.

Comment: Re logging in and changing language. I see no actualy way to change language at logon.. I see text which mentions changing language, but there is no option (buttons or suchlike).. perhaps that is because I only have Australian English enabled.... and I have run all the commands above.. so it is stil a mystery at the moment...

Comment: @red.bear: Try installing `language-pack-en` and `language-support-en`, then repeat the process above.

Answer (score 1):

I tried editing locale file and choosing different languages at login.

Filtering for broken packages with Synaptic and completely removing the 9 offending packages worked for me (libreoffice and python uno).

But, I am unable to install LibreOffice without apparently corrupting the package manager. It does, however, install.

I'm on 11.04 i386.
Disclaimer: There was a power failure during the last part of my installation as Ubuntu was downloading updates.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but going to 
System > Administration > Language Support 
may solve your problem because it may ask 
you to install some packages and then it 
will be fine!! It worked for me so i guess
it'll do the same to you!!

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
export LC_ALL="zh_CN.utf8"
ibus-setup
```

and select one of of the options for input method as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (most noticeable in Thunderbird) to the en_AU example here - but i'm from en_NZ - and after some trial-and-error with Ubuntu 17.10 my fix was to update ~/.pam_environment, replacing all other entries (mostly en_AU and en_US) with en_NZ, then rebooting.

A shame that you can't just set your locale and have it do what it claims to do - most disappointed that that running dpkg-configure locales doesn't actually seem to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to deploy Rails application with Capistrano, from macbook m1 pro to Ubuntu 22.04 server.

#### In ubuntu 22.04 server:

I added the following to `~/.bash_profile`

```
#fix for locale issues when connecting to ubuntu servers
export LANG="en_US.utf8"
export LANGUAGE="en_US.utf8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.utf8"
```

I run these commands:

```
$ export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

- Click up and down arrow to focus "en_US.UTF-8"
- Click TAB to focus
- Click Enter

Restart Ubuntu server

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

Then I run this command

```
$ locale
```

Output:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

Looks like everything is fine. But the issue is not solved.

#### In macbook m1 pro:

**Then I updated settings on mac terminal**

Terminal -> Settings... -> Profiles -> Advanced -> Uncheck “Set locale environment variables on startup” You will then need to quit the Terminal application, and open terminal. This issue should be fixed.

**Now I run `cap staging deploy` command, in macbook m1 pro, works!**