# Some texts appear as "Label empty"

Tags: text, unicode, locale, translation, dialog

I've got a problem with some of the texts not appearing in Ubuntu 11.04. I use the Spanish translation of Ubuntu and reinstalling the packages didn't solve the problem.

You will find some screenshots appended. In the first screenshot a "Label Empty" text can be seen where it should say "Log off" ("Cerrar sesión" in spanish).

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

The second one shows de Log off screen dialog, where te button is actually empty (says nothing) and there are some strange characters in the question dialog.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Does anybody know how to fix these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling the packages won't necessarily help because localization info was separated in Ubuntu. You may want to open Settings, Language support (icon with United Nations flag) and see if it prompts for localization not being completely installed.

The font issue is specially challenging because these Unicode symbols should be supported by default. If you type `locale` at a terminal, will the output look like `LANG=es_ES.UTF-8` ? If it is, try selecting a different font like 'Ubuntu' or 'Sans' in the Appearance settings.

Comment: Strange things are happening :| gnome-language-selector wouldn't even start from the GUI. Launching it from the CLI says there's a segment violation, even when reinstalling it... will keep looking for a solution to that.

On the other hand, the output of "locale" in the prompt says:
LANG=es_ES@euro
LANGUAGE=es_ES:es_ES@euro:en
LC_CTYPE="es_ES"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES"
LC_TIME="es_ES"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES"
LC_PAPER="es_ES"
LC_NAME="es_ES"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES"
LC_ALL=es_ES

No UTF at all :(. Thanx

Comment: You might want to try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and I would sincerely recommend to switch to es_ES.UTF-8.

Comment: After some investigation wondering how to set UTF-8 locales, the suggested solution deffinitely worked for me!! Thanx aquaherd :)

Comment: The solution is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the file `/etc/enviroment` this way could help:

```
LANGUAGE="es_ES:es:en_GB:en"
LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
```

This page (spanish) describes how the locales work in Ubuntu, and lists the configuration files involved.

http://misdocumentos.net/wiki/linux/locales