# Gparted Partition editor not working

Tags: gtk, gparted, locale

I had Windows and installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows.

I want to allocate suitable disk space to Ubuntu. I installed the Gparted Parition Editor from the Software Center.

**My problem is:** It closes down as soon as I open it.The same happens when I try to open it through Terminal.

This is the message I get in the terminal:

```
(process:2977): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================

(gpartedbin:2977): glibmm-ERROR **: 
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

This is the result of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x7434793e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2   *       81920    29044735    14481408    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        29044736   606384127   288669696    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       606386176  1953521663   673567744    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       606388224   817569791   105590784    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       817571840  1543921663   363174912    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7      1543923712  1748721663   102398976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8      1748723712  1953521663   102398976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

`sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD10JPVT-75A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  41.1MB  41.1MB  primary   fat16        diag
 2      41.9MB  14.9GB  14.8GB  primary   ntfs         boot
 3      14.9GB  310GB   296GB   primary   ntfs
 4      310GB   1000GB  690GB   extended               lba
 5      310GB   419GB   108GB   logical   ntfs
 6      419GB   790GB   372GB   logical   ntfs
 7      790GB   895GB   105GB   logical   ntfs
 8      895GB   1000GB  105GB   logical   ntfs
```

Comment: Try running it from the command line and see if there is any output: `sudo gparted`

Comment: Please make it clear whether you have done a Wubi installation (= Ubuntu **within** Windows) or whether you installed Ubuntu alongside Windows in its own partition.

Comment: @psusi If I run it through terminal.It happens the same but I have the following messages.I don't understand it. I am new to Ubuntu.                                              (process:3347): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
 Using the fallback 'C' locale.
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================

(gpartedbin:3347): glibmm-ERROR **: 
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Comment: @vasa1 . Honestly I don't know the difference between the two but is there any way I can check that and let you know.

Comment: Edit your question and add the information there rather than paste it all fubar as a comment.

Comment: Also, edit your question to include the information you get when you run `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l` from the terminal.

Comment: Please remember to [format your post properly](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help). This assures you have a high quality question, which will receive the high quality answers it deserves! Thanks and good luck!

Comment: @FEichinger thanks a lot for the help.You are right about the formatting. I am new to Ubuntu and this site.I am trying to learn it. Thanks once again.

Comment: @user12448 No problem. We're here to help. :)

Comment: See if this answer applies: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them

Comment: Also, if you plan to shrink the Windows partition, it's a good idea to degrag and use Disk Management from Windows to shrink the drive.

Comment: @user117123 . I tried with the disk management in windows.But I am not sure how it should be . Or what exactly I should do.I have both Ubuntu and Windows  C drive .