# Setting LANG for SublimeText from Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, locale

I am trying to run SublimeText with the package control addon and each time I open it using the Unity launcher I receive this error.

[image]

So far I have tried following the instructions provided by [Ubuntu Community Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale), setting it in all of the mentioned places and then restarting has not fixed the problem.

I've also followed the steps found [on the package control github](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/532) page to no avail.

This does work when I am launching SublimeText from the command line so I am guessing it is a Unity specific problem, does anyone know how to set LANG correctly when launching SublimeText from Unity?

Edit: Adding installation details,
I installed using the 64-bit SublimeText3 .deb found here, http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime-text_build-3059_amd64.deb

Package Control was installed using the simple method found here, https://sublime.wbond.net/installation

Answer (score 1):

I installed `sublimetext` using the ppa method and `Package control` with the "simple method" described [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation), it works out of the box with Ubuntu 13.10 (Unity).

To reproduce your problem I tried to force LANG-C to start sublimetext by modifying the .desktop file. I think you could try the same tweak to start it by this time forcing `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop
```

And copy the following lines into the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=bash -c "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F"
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;Utility;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.21

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=bash -c "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=bash -c "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file"
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Comment: I tried using that .desktop file but I am still getting that error.  If it helps I am using 12.04

Comment: I'll try on a 12.04 system too, could you please detail what installation method did you use? (ppa, .deb, tar.gz, ...) for both sublime and package control.

Comment: I added installation details... I can try the ppa method to see if that changes things.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
my LANG is set system wide but sublimetext 3 package manager not picking it up.

I just did the workaround and put LANG=en_US.UTF-8 before the application path in its icon launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with sublimeT3. First on a terminal I ran the next command:

```
$echo $LOCAL
```

And the output was an empty line.

Next I ran:

```
$locale
```

An this was the output:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=POSIX
LC_NUMERIC=POSIX
LC_TIME=POSIX
LC_COLLATE=POSIX
LC_MONETARY=POSIX
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=POSIX
LC_NAME=POSIX
LC_ADDRESS=POSIX
LC_TELEPHONE=POSIX
LC_MEASUREMENT=POSIX
LC_IDENTIFICATION=POSIX
LC_ALL=POSIX
```

I tried to reset the locales with some of the answers given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them), but everything was unsuccessful, every time the "locale" command gave the same output.
Even my **/etc/default/locale** seemed to be right:

```
$cat /etc/default/locale
```

Output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_CO.UTF-8"
```

Because of this I wondered if maybe something was overriding the environment variables. My **.pam_environment** file seemed to be correct:

```
$cat .pam_environment
```

Output:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_CO.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=letter
```

So I ran the next command which gave me the clue of what was going on:

```
$cat .bashrc | grep LANG
```

Here the output:

```
unset LANG
```

I don't know when or how, but I ended up with two lines on my .bashrc that overrode the value of "locale" variables. I'm not pasting the whole bash file, but the two key lines were these:

```
unset LANG
export LC_ALL=POSIX
```

By commenting them on the bash file and a reboot, voila! my locale was set up as it was intended to, and sublimeT3 stopped complaining. It's been more than a year since this was formulated, but maybe it could help someone else!