# Can't switch back to German

Tags: 14.04, language-support

I switched my Ubuntu with gnome-language-selector to English. Now I can't go back to German. Everything is in English but the console outputs.

Everything in settings an conf files seems to be ok:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiUgQ.png (the menu above is from gnome-terminal)

```
> cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG=""
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="de_DE:en_GB:en"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX

> cat .pam_environment 
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=a4
LANGUAGE=de_DE:en_GB:en
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

what I did else:

```
> dpkg-reconfigure locales 
> sudo update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall locales
```

and reboots - lots of reboots.

what else can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked http://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them ?

Comment: yes, I've done what's said there, but /etc/environment does not have any language settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the line

```
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

from `/etc/default/locale` and reboot.

Comment: almost ... after setting LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8" nautilus and the desktop where also back to german

Comment: @koem: LC_MESSAGES should not be set in `/etc/default/locale` at all, since it breaks the way the GUIs for controlling the display language work. OTOH LANG should indeed be set to "de_DE.UTF-8". Since you said you run `sudo update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`, it ought to be...

Comment: @koem: You should have sticked with Language Support to begin with. Then you wouldn't have messed it up. ;)