# When I've set LC_ALL=C (for English output on the command line) how can I return to my original locale (nl_NL)?

Tags: command-line, locale

I've seen useful posts on [LC_ALL=C](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264283/switch-command-output-language-from-native-language-to-english) and [resolving problems with locale settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them), but those look a bit too complicated to me.

In a session started with `LC_ALL=C bash` I've tried the obvious `LC_ALL=nl_NL`, but that gave warnings, so I'm unsure if that is the proper way to go when setting `LC_ALL=C` (without `bash`)

Comment: Have you tried just setting it to the empty string i.e. `LC_ALL=`? AFAIK it is typically unset by default - only if set, it overrides the individual locale variables such as `LC_NUMERIC`, `LC_MESSAGES` etc.

Comment: A less intrusive way to get English output in terminal is `LANGUAGE=en_US`

Comment: after LC_ALL=C for me the locale still shows "LC_ALL=" 
Also, after applying LC_ALL=C and then LC_ALL=nl-NL, I noticed the command line output with wrong special characters, missing UTF-8 apparently.
Maybe I should have used LC_ALL=nl-NL.UTF-8 .. Can try.

Comment: It's `nl_NL.UTF-8` - with an underscore, not dash.

Comment: you may need to type `export LC_ALL=C` to change `locale` the first time

Answer (score 10):

@steeldriver is right, unsurprisingly. All you need to do is

```
LC_ALL=
```

to restore all your normal locale settings for the session.

Example:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

setting `LC_ALL=` restores the original `locale` settings

```
$ LC_ALL=
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: There's some nice discussion over on our sister site [What does “LC_ALL=C” do?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for adding that. I saw it reading the OP's linked posts. Very illuminating :)

Answer (score 6):

The probable reason why `LC_ALL=nl_NL` gave you warnings is that `nl_NL` is a locale for enabling ISO-8859-1 encoding, and it's typically not generated on an Ubuntu system. `LC_ALL=nl_NL.UTF-8` should work. As others have said, `LC_ALL=` (i.e. disabling it) works too.