# 16.04 LTS date format in browser and apps

Tags: format, date

Sorry if I'm asking a stale question, found no solution so far. 
Date is displayed as mm/dd/yyyy with 12 hour time in browser **input type="date"** fields and in Libre Calc as well. I need to set it to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm, but I see no way to do it.
Regional Formats are set to Russian, and I switched it back and forth between en US, en GB and ru ru variants, hitting the Apply System-wide button and doing relogin every time as well. 
The time in system tray is affected, browser and libre calc are not. I'm at a loss.

[image]

Comment: What Browser are you using? You can set the date format for Libre Office referring to [this guide](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/24722/how-to-change-the-default-date-format-in-calc-to-show-4-digit-years/).

Comment: I use Chrome, but the issue was not restricted to the mentioned programs, I have a bunch that should use the local format. So like more a global issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locale settings are not right. How can I reset them?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me. So if anyone has the same problem hope it helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159950/changing-short-date-format-in-ubuntu

Comment: Mark this as correct answer so others know this is solved :)

Comment: @FatalMerlin This is not possible sooner than in 48 hours. https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Melebius good to know.

Comment: k, I'll try not to forget. Looks like you basically just need to add something like LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8" to /etc/environment . weird stuff

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu recently and ran into same very problem. Googled, found my own topic :) But, editing etc/environment didn't help. What helped was putting 'English UK' on top of the list in Language Support > Language tab. So here it is, future me, that should be done too.