# Gnome-classic language turned into Chinese, how do I change it back to English?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, locale

[image]My newly installed Ubuntu 12.04 gnome-classic just turned into chinese locale after reboot, how do I change it back to English?

I can't find any language menus, and the ones I opened are, well, in chinese...

When I open a terminal and execute `gnome-language-selector`, I get lots of this in the prompt:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

If I go to the Language section in Users, I only get the options in the picture.

Comment: I solved it following the instructions of this post:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/2855/locale-reset-lost-settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you login into the Unity session, because I'm not sure where I can find all of these options in a Gnome Classic session.

---

Click on your username in the upper right corner of the screen, and choose the bottom option in the menu that pops out.

[image: User menu]

In the dialog that opens, the second option allows you to change your language.

[image: User account]

Change it back to English, or whatever language you like. Then, reboot.

Answer (score 20):

Solution:

1. Edit `/etc/default/locale`:

   ```
   LANG="en_US"
   LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
   ```
2. Edit `~/.pam_environment`:

   ```
   LANG=en_US
   Language=en_US
   ```

Logout and Login or Reboot.

Comment: Worked for me, was hard to navigate menus in chinese...

Comment: Worked here too, especially after editing the second file (.pam_enviroment) - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem y I solved just one min ago.

You have to select the first language option, and then relogin the Gnome session.

NOTE: if you do any changes from the Unity session, you will not sew a result.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Having just faced a similar issue, I resolved it by translating my language choice into traditional Chinese using Google Translate, then pattern-matched.  In the screenshot in the question, the first entry translates as "English" and the second as "English (United Kingdom)".  Picking one and logging out then in should reset the UI.