# Strange display language in gnome shell

Tags: gnome, locale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnome-classic language turned into Chinese, how do I change it back to English?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132347/gnome-classic-language-turned-into-chinese-how-do-i-change-it-back-to-english)

I logged in `gnome-shell`, and found that the display language is set to some strange Asian language (I think) without my prompt.

I tried to change the locale settings but found that the default language is English (how?) despite of that strange language.

Here's a snapshot, See the strange word instead of "Activity":

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/61gqp]

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Output of locale:

```
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=zh_CN:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Output of locale -a:

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_CH.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
zh_CN.utf8
zh_SG.utf8
```

**Solved:**
[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/132350/88386) did it.

Comment: We probably need more info, can you edit your question and the output of: `locale -a; locale`

Comment: Similar questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2855/locale-reset-lost-settings -- http://askubuntu.com/questions/132347/gnome-classic-language-turned-into-chinese-how-do-i-change-it-back-to-english

Comment: Many thanks. An answer in the second link did it. Sorry for bothering. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution #1

In Ubuntu, this command will show the language-related packages you have installed:

```
dpkg -l language-pack*|grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}'
```

Purge any packages (using the ubuntu software center or synaptic or otherwise) that are not english (*-en-*) and reboot.

#### Solution #2

Try this:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US:en LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8 LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

..and reboot.

Comment: These are the results:

language-pack-en
language-pack-en-base
language-pack-gnome-en
language-pack-gnome-en-base
language-pack-kde-en
language-pack-kde-en-base

They are all English. Strange.

Comment: Sorry. Nothing changed.