# Mysql strange installations problems (logger: command not found)

Tags: apt, dpkg, mysql

This problem is really strange, I have tried many ways to solve but nothing worked.
My last output was:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "pl_PL.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst: line 146: logger: command not found
ATTENTION: An error has occured. More info is in the syslog!
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst: line 236: logger: command not found
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I really don't know how to fix that, guys please help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [locale: Reset lost settings](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2855/locale-reset-lost-settings)

Answer (score 25):

Had the same issue with mysql-server-5.6 and this solution hs helped me:

[launchpad: Bug #392051: [Karmic] logger command not found](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/392051)

Basically, the program `logger` got messed up;

It can be recreated by reinstalling the package `bsdutils`:

`apt-get --reinstall install bsdutils`

or

`aptitude reinstall bsdutils`

Comment: This also worked for me. Using a VPS from Hosting24

Answer (score 1):

Your "locales" have not been generated yet, or not properly.

Try this:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 pl_PL pl_PL.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then try again to install MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

This is the original answer referred from this block:

https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/

**Update Locales:**

```
sudo locale-gen fi_FI.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
apt-get update
```

**Run this command below**

On your server and it will replace all of the  `archive.ubuntu.com`  and  `security.ubuntu.com` package repository URLs with  `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/us.old-releases.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g'/etc/apt/sources.list

sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g'/etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get update
```