# Dependency problems

Tags: dependencies, locale

I am not able to install anything because I get the follworing dependecy issues:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of locales:
 libc6 (2.19-18) breaks locales (<< 2.19) and is installed.
  Version of locales to be configured is 2.13+git20120306-3.
dpkg: error processing locales (--configure):
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: libc6 2.19-18 is not an Ubuntu package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [try this](https://askubuntu.com/a/506245/186134):

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 pl_PL pl_PL.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

But if that doesn't work, [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/519783/186134) may help:

> [launchpad: Bug #392051: [Karmic] logger command not found](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/392051)
>
> Basically, the program `locales` got messed up;
>
> It can be recreated by reinstalling the package `locales`:
>
> ```
> apt-get --reinstall install locales
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> aptitude reinstall locales
> ```

Comment: this worked: http://askubuntu.com/questions/506243/mysql-strange-installations-problems-logger-command-not-found/519783#519783