# MySQL 5.6 dpkg install error, even after complete uninstall

Tags: dpkg, mysql

I am having a error whilst installing MySQL 5.6 from downloaded deb and from apt:

```
nginx@LBNginx:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 121037 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) over (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
2015-10-27 19:31:17 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-10-27 19:31:17 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 7666 ...
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.27 started; log sequence number 1626007
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] Binlog end
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-10-27 19:31:17 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-10-27 19:31:19 7666 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1626017
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
```

I have completely removed MySQL from the system and tried again but still no avail.

Note: I am running Ubuntu Server Trusty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first remove `mysql-server` completely using commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

then try to install it again.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

if you installing with dpkg command and if it show any dependency on other package then run command :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then try again to install

**EDIT:** [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1435081) is bug with `mysql-server-5.6` so try lower version of `mysql-server`. if you want to install `mysql-server-5.6` then you can use [this](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6) PPA.

create any file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
```

and paste below lines and save it.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu trusty main
```

and update it

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install it using command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

it is tested on `Ubuntu 14.04` .
 [Here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6) is PPA available for Ubuntu Version `12.04` ,`14.04` ,`14.10`, `15.04` and `15.10`.

Comment: It ends up with the same error.

Comment: after removing completely . these file are available . /etc/mysql/   and /var/lib/mysql/ if yes then remove it using command  `sudo rm -r /etc/mysql/`

Comment: I end up with `
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: reinstall   `apt-get --reinstall install bsdutils` . reference http://askubuntu.com/questions/506243/mysql-strange-installations-problems-logger-command-not-found

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1435081  here is bug with mysql-server 5.6 so try with lower version

Comment: @Dranes  try my updated answer

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 (now quite outdated) the advice to remove complete and re-install worked like a charm.  That yielded mysql version 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue when I followed following [tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/mysql.html#instgde-prereq-mysql-ubuntu) to install mysql 5.6 on ubuntu 14.

I had installed Ubuntu using vagrant. I had assigned only 512 MB to the virtual machine.

To fix it I did following things.

1) Increased the virtual machine Memory to 1024MB

`config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     vb.memory = "1024"
   end`

2) Run `vagrant reload` command

3) Then uninstalled the MySql

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 mysql-client-5.6
```

4) Then again installed MySql and it worked for me.

Comment: I have same problem. Because Memory defaul is 512MB. Because of something it is didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with mysql-common, you need to use mysql-common 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 for mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27

After you executed

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

try with this https://gist.github.com/dranes/e65bbaa8c7800fd12575

Answer (score 0):

Atlast this worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install -f mysql-server
```

I added **-f** in the command, after removing mysql completely. That did the trick!